# Constructor variable's name Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I have to override an interface method I need to search for the documentation every time I implement them because in the code it just appears as "p0" "p1" "p2".
Is there any way to the actual name of the variables inside Android Studio?

```
 private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context) : BaseAdapter() {

        override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {

            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable them by pressing `CMD-SHIFT-A`, and typing in `"Toggle parameter name hints"` (probably substitute `CMD` for `CTRL` if you're on Windows).

Also, if you press `CMD-P` with will list the parameter names for a given function.

Comment: I just tried what you said but the names "p0" "p1" still the same